# Android webview loadurl "/" character falls

Tags: java, android, webview, urlencode, url-encoding

I'm trying to load an url with webview. My url is http://my-hit.com/ahmet-kaya/2 . It is not loading because url changing to http://my-hit.com/ahmet-kaya2 while loading. I have controlled the url in on pagefinished function ; the "/" character falls. I tried %2F instead of "/" but did not work. Please help me.

`myurl = http://my-hit.com/ahmet-kaya;`

```
      String mynewurl;
            CurrentPage = CurrentPage + 1;

            //Integer.valueOf(CurrentPage).toString();

             mynewurl = myurl +"/"+ CurrentPage;


            mProgress = new ProgressDialog(MainActivty.this);
            mProgress.setMessage("Yükleniyor...");
            mProgress.setCancelable(false);
            mProgress.show();

            final boolean loadingFinished = true;
            web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {



                 @Override
                 public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
                 {                  

                     /* This call inject JavaScript into the page which just finished loading. */
                    view.loadUrl("javascript:window.HTMLOUT.showHTML('<head>'+document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML+'</head>');"); 
                    view.clearCache(true);
                 }
             });             
             /* load a web page */


            web.loadUrl(mynewurl);
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to enable javascript in settings for the webview. Try using this code:

```
 WebSettings settings = web.getSettings();
 settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Comment: I m setting setJavaScriptEnabled. Javascript already is working . The issue is related loadurl function and encoding.

Comment: String myurl = "http://my-hit.com/ahmet-kaya/"; try on this way and then just add the page. There should not be a problem with encoding.